# Writing to Socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am making a simple 1 to 1 server-client chat application using sockets.Basically there is a server which can communicate with a single client at a time.What I am trying to do is client should send a string to server and the server has to send it back to the client with changing the case of the string(upper to lower and vice-versa).The problem is the string is sent to the server but the response from the server never came on account of that the client is unable to send other string.
Output of the program:-

root@User:~/Desktop/Aadil/SystemPracticum/Programs/Assignment5# ./Server 4000

the message from client is message1

root@User:~/Desktop/Aadil/SystemPracticum/Programs/Assignment5# ./Client localhost 4000

enter the message message1

enter the message message2

Thank You
Here is my code 
Server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 
void ChangeCase(char *string){
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]){
      //  printf("converting\n");
        if(string[i] <= 90 && string[i] >= 65)
            string[i] += 32;
        else
            string[i] -= 32;
        ++i;
    }

}
int main(int counter, char *string[]){
    if(counter < 2){
        perror("erro! please provide port no.\n");
    }else{
        int  server_socket_file_descriptor,client_socket_file_descriptor,
        port_no,message_length,client_length;
        char buffer[256];//buffer to be used for storing messages
        struct sockaddr_in server_address,client_address;

        server_socket_file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        /*it creates new socket the first argument AF_INET is used for internet domain 
          and second argument SOCK_STREAM is used for stream socket 
          third argument 0 means the default protocol for stram socket which is tcp*/
        if(server_socket_file_descriptor < 0)
            perror("\t\t\t\t=====!!!cant create a socket!!!=====\n");

        bzero((char*)&server_address,sizeof(server_address));//set all value to 0

        //set port no. by converting port from char* to integer            
        port_no = atoi(string[1]);

        /*now initialize the server_address
          server_address is a struct of sockaddr_in type which has four field in it
          we need to initialize 3 of them
        */
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        //convert port no. to network byte order
        server_address.sin_port = htons(port_no);
        //set server ip address to the machines ip address in my case it is 10.8.3.236            
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

        /*now we need to bind the server with socket created*/
        if(bind(server_socket_file_descriptor,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
                sizeof(server_address)) < 0){
            perror("\t\t\t\t\t====error in binding====\n");
            return 0;
        }
        //since socket is bind correctly I am not checking for the error
        listen(server_socket_file_descriptor,8);
        /*listening to socket. 8 represent the maximum client that 
         can wait in queue to connect to the server*/

        //we are done with the server :D

        client_length = sizeof(client_address);
        client_socket_file_descriptor = accept(server_socket_file_descriptor,
                                               (struct sockaddr*)&client_address,
                                               &client_length);
        if(client_socket_file_descriptor < 0)
             perror("\t\t\t\t unable to connect to client");

        while(1){
            bzero(buffer,256);
            message_length = read(client_socket_file_descriptor,buffer,255);

            if(message_length < 0)
                perror("\t\t\t\t error in reading from socket\n");

            printf("\t\t\t\tthe message from client is %s\n",buffer);
            ChangeCase(buffer);

            message_length = write(client_socket_file_descriptor,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
            if(message_length < 0)
                perror("\t\t\t\t error writing to socket\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int file_descriptor,message_length,port_no;
        char Buffer[256];//to store the message
        //to store the address of the server to     which     we want to connect
        struct sockaddr_in server_address; 
        struct hostent *server;//hostent defines the host computer on internet
        if(argc < 3){
            printf("\t\t\t please provide ip address and port no.\n");
            return 1;
        } 
        port_no = atoi(argv[2]);

        if((file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
            return 1;
        } 

        memset(&server_address, '0', sizeof(server_address)); 

        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        //convert port no. to network byte order
        server_address.sin_port = htons(port_no);
        //set server ip address to the machines ip address in my case it is 10.8.3.236
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if(connect(file_descriptor,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
                                   sizeof(server_address))<0){
            perror("error in connection\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while(1){
            memset(Buffer, '0',sizeof(Buffer));
            printf("\t\t\t\t\tenter the message\n");
            fgets(Buffer,255,stdin);
            message_length = write(file_descriptor,Buffer,strlen(Buffer));

            if(message_length<0)
                perror("\t\t\t\terror in writing\n");

            memset(Buffer,'0',sizeof(Buffer));
            message_length = read(file_descriptor,Buffer,255);

            if(message_length < 0)
                perror("\t\t\terror in reading from buffer\n");
            else{
                printf("%s\n",Buffer);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Any output from the server and client? You could add a few more debug printfs for good cases to show which steps of the connection buildup have been successful (bind, listen, accept on the server side; connect on the client side).

Comment: @Aadil Ahmad please paste the output of client & server

Comment: @Aadil Ahmad pleeeeaaase, do not put additional information in comments, edit your question!

Comment: @AadilAhmad so do not enter these information in comment. Put them in question!

Comment: @AadilAhmad You can see for yourself that putting code or output into comments is completely illegible. If you want your question answered please do as you've been asked, twice.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is located in this line in your server code:

```
message_length = write(client_socket_file_descriptor,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

Note that this line always sends 256 bytes back to the client.  For a string like "message1", that means it will send back "MESSAGE1" followed by 248 NUL/zero bytes.

Depending on how the TCP stack decides to break up those bytes, your client's read() call may receive those bytes in different partial sequences, and if any partial sequence it receives starts with a NUL/zero byte, it will print out as an empty string.

In order to better see what's going on, you might replace this line in your client:

```
printf("%s\n",Buffer);
```

with something like this:

```
printf("[%s]\n",Buffer);
```

I'd also recommend changing your server to specify strlen(buffer) as the final argument to write() rather than sizeof(buffer).